# syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am getting this error when I run my Bash script:

**syntax error: unexpected end of file**

Cant really find where the error is, been looking for hours and still get this error.

Here is the script hope some one cant point me in the right direction:

```
#!/bin/bash 


BACKUPDIR=~/backup
SCRIPTDIR=~/respaldar
BACKUPFILE=/respaldo.$(date +%F).bz2
BACKUPHOST=199.21.112.70
COUNT=$(ls $BACKUPDIR | wc -l)
TRESHOLD=7




if [[ ! -e $BACKUPDIR ]]
then
     echo "Creating Backup Directory because it doesn\'t exist !"
    mkdir ~/backup
    COUNT=0
#    exit 0
else
   COUNT=$(ls $BACKUPDIR | wc -l)
fi




if [[ $COUNT -le $THRESHOLD ]]
then
      tar -cjvf $BACKUPDIR/$BACKUPFILE $SCRIPTDIR 
      if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then echo "Problems Creating Backup File;"  fi
      scp $BACKUPDIR/$BACKUPFILE $BACKUPHOST:
      if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then echo "Problems Copying Backup File to Backup Host;" fi
fi







#END
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: `if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then echo "Problems Creating Backup File;"  fi` should have a semicolon before `fi`.

Comment: See http://www.shellcheck.net/ for an automated testing tool.

Comment: `COUNT=$(ls $BACKUPDIR | wc -l)` is damned silly. `files=( "$backupdir"/* ); count=${#files[@]}` has the same effect without all the overhead of doing all the fork and exec calls necessary to spawn `ls` in a pipeline... and doesn't depend on the implementation-defined behavior of `ls`. (`ls` output is supposed to guarantee one-entry-per-line, but only when it's not going to a terminal, in which case it's implementation-defined... so if you rely on what `ls` looks like on a given platform when you run it to your screen, it might be giving completely different output going to a pipeline!)

Comment: now now Charles don't get so upset, we've all been there. Anyway probably a good idea to quote the variables with `tar` and `scp` e.g. `tar -cjvf "$BACKUPDIR/$BACKUPFILE" "$SCRIPTDIR"` in case of spaces in file/directory names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I copyed the whole stuff to [vi](/questions/tagged/vi) and it spotted the same thing as `fedorqui`:

```
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then echo "Problems Creating Backup File;"  fi
...
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then echo "Problems Copying Backup File to Backup Host;" fi
```

The `;` is before `"` and should be after.

I would suggest to use a shorter solution in both cases:

```
[ $? -ne 0 ] && echo "Problems Creating Backup File">&2 && exit 1
```

This will exit if [tar](/questions/tagged/tar) fails. Or even the more talkative version:

```
tar -cjvf $BACKUPDIR/$BACKUPFILE $SCRIPTDIR || \
    { echo "Problems Creating Backup File">&2;exit 1;}
```

Or if You want to see an error message only if the whole process fails:

```
tar -cjvf $BACKUPDIR/$BACKUPFILE $SCRIPTDIR && \
    scp $BACKUPDIR/$BACKUPFILE $BACKUPHOST: || \
    { echo "Backup failed">&2;exit 1;}
```

Comment: Even shorter: `tar -cjvf "$BACKUPDIR/$BACKUPFILE" "$SCRIPTDIR" || echo "Problems Creating Backup File" && exit 1`

Comment: @doubleDown: `... || ... && exit` is not proper! `exit` will be done even if `tar` finishes w/o problem.

Comment: @doubleDown: You should use `{ ... ;}` to group complex commands within 1 block. ex: `tar -cjvf "$BACKUPDIR/$BACKUPFILE" "$SCRIPTDIR" || { echo "Problems Creating Backup File" && exit 1 ;} `

Comment: @OlivierDulac Yes, IMHO I did.

Comment: I was adressing doubleDown ^^